# Why are my ASPX pages not being compressed with Gzip enabled?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, compression, gzip

So I set up gzip compression within IIS 6.

I enabled the compression for both static files and application files.  I set up a temp directory with the size of 1,024 MB.

I modified the Metbase to include: htm,html,js,css,aspx,xml

I set the compression level to 9.

I added a WSE, called HttoCompression and set it to the gzip.dll aset it to "Allow".

I reset IIS.

I notice that my css, xml and js files are being compressed, but ASPX pages are not.

Did I miss something?

Comment: I supposed you have checked this out?
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5bce429d-c4a7-4f9e-a619-5972497b932a.mspx

Comment: Or maybe this one will help you:
http://eduncan911.com/blog/enabling-http-compression-with-aspx.aspx
Looks promising.

Comment: The Microsoft article just shows you how to edit the metabase from a script, I used the Metabase explorer to do that. so yeah that's done. checking the second link you posted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default static file types .txt, .htm, and .html & dynamic file types .exe, .dll, and .asp are set for compression in IIS.

So to add other file types you need to configure custom settings for each compression option by editing the metabase or alternatively — in the case of the compression directory — by using IIS Manager.

For more explanations plz visit http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Have yo followed these steps correctly?

```
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322603
```

Also, I would highly recommend Port 80's solution:

```
http://www.port80software.com/products/httpzip/
```

Comment: I did all the things in the first link, I'll check port 80

Comment: Isn't Port 80 a 3rd party product?

Comment: Yes, but with IIS 6.0 I've found it removes the headaches of setting up and managing compression.  IIS 7 and 7.5 are pain-free.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go and edit the IIS Metabase file. If you dont want to resrart IIS / the server once you have done it click alolow live metabase edits in IIS

From the MS article you can get some patch results.

Easier post to follow (From Mr Atwood), basicly just cut and paste over the current values. 
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000059.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out I put the aspx extension in the wrong spot in the MetaBase.xml file

When I put it under HcFileExtensions it did not work. When I put it under HcScriptFileExtensions it did work.